# Get sum of last 5 rows for each unique id

Tags: sum

[image]This is the query I'm using currently

```
SELECT SUM(score) as score FROM (SELECT p2.score FROM performance_buzz as p2 WHERE p2.player_id = 922 ORDER BY p2.id DESC LIMIT 5) as performance_buzz
```

But in the above query I need to pass `player_id` manually and I don't want to do that. I want to do this with the mysql way because I want to use this query as subquery for getting last 5 rows sum of score for each player

```
SELECT performance_buzz.id, performance_buzz.score as last_score, performance_buzz.name

FROM `performance_buzz` 

LEFT JOIN performance_buzz m2 ON (performance_buzz.name = m2.name AND performance_buzz.id < m2.id)  

WHERE m2.id IS NULL 

GROUP BY performance_buzz.name 

ORDER BY performance_buzz.id DESC
```

Comment: Are you trying to get sum of last five scores for all unique players in the system? Depending on your performance requirements there are multiple ways to do that.

Comment: but this sum of last 5 score is important to get using mysql. because my order by column depends on this sum of last 5 rows score.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

should be like this:

```
select player_id, sum(score) score
from
(
    SELECT 
        @row_number:=CASE
            WHEN @player_id = player_id THEN @row_number + 1
            ELSE 1
        END AS rn,
        @player_id:=player_id as player_id,
        score
    FROM
        performance_buzz,(SELECT @player_id:=0,@row_number:=0) as t
   order by player_id, id desc
) a
where rn <= 5
group by player_id
```