# How to select last 5 rows of each unique records in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Using python 3 am trying for each uniqe row in the column 'Name' to get the last 5 records from the column 'Number'. How exactly can this be done in python?
My df looks like this:

```
Name    Number
a   5
a   6
b   7
b   8
a   9
a   10
b   11
b   12
a   9
b   8
```

I saw same exmples(like this one [Get sum of last 5 rows for each unique id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48111090/get-sum-of-last-5-rows-for-each-unique-id) ) in SQL but that is time consuming and I would like to learn how to do it in python.

My expected output df would be like this:

```
Name    1   2   3   4   5
a   5   6   9   10  9
b   7   8   11  12  8
```

Comment: This should get you quite close: `df.groupby('Name').tail(5)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need something like this:

```
df_out = df.groupby('Name').tail(5)
df_out.set_index(['Name', df_out.groupby('Name').cumcount() +1])['Number'].unstack()
```

Output:

```
      1  2   3   4  5
Name                 
a     5  6   9  10  9
b     7  8  11  12  8
```

Comment: Scott this does the trick really nice. Thank you very much. I'll play with this and try to add more(like an average of the numbers) so I can learn.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) after a [`groupby.cumcount()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html)

```
df1=df.groupby('Name').tail(5)
final=(df1.assign(k=df1.groupby('Name').cumcount()+1)
          .pivot(index='Name', columns='k', values='Number')
          .reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1))
print(final)
```

---

```
  Name  1  2   3   4  5
0    a  5  6   9  10  9
1    b  7  8  11  12  8
```

Comment: This doesn't just get the last 5, does it?

Comment: @IanS or even better same approach with `tail()` edited the answer. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for the support guys. You are right @anky_91 tail() is a more easy approach for a beginner like me. Thank you again :)